# Is 41% of all code on GitHub AI-generated?

Tags: software, programming, ai

I read on [decrypt.co](https://decrypt.co/147191/no-human-programmers-five-years-ai-stability-ceo):

> Data from GitHub reveals that "41% of all code right now is AI generated" [Mostaque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emad_Mostaque) remarked.

Is is true that 41% of all code on GitHub is AI-generated? They don't provide any reference supporting that claim.

That sounds rather high to me, unless perhaps a small fraction of repo or orgs are dumping some massive amount of possibly broken AI-generated code, which would boost that percentage.

Comment: The quote (from an AI company) goes on to say "a testament to AI's growing popularity over cryptocurrency". Chalk and cheese, or chalking one up by grasping at cheese straws?

Comment: In the other link, its CEO declares that AI investment "will be biggest bubble of all time". What happens to big bubbles?

Comment: Hence my skepticism.

Comment: The thing about GitHub is that you can create thousands of accounts and fill their quota with meaningless projects, be they AI generated or not even software at all. MS doesn't seem too concerned with that for the moment.

Comment: @Fizz yes, that's why I wrote "unless perhaps a small fraction of repo or orgs are dumping some massive amount of possibly broken AI-generated code, which would boost that percentage."

Comment: If that is happening, you could soon say "99% of crap is posted by AI".

Comment: Are they having false positives from auto-generated boilerplate code, possibly? That’s the first thing that comes to mind, and I’d argue it’s not the same as AI-generated. Would be *interesting* to see if they ran their heuristics on all commits *prior* to the release of ChatGPT/etc

Comment: I would say that "41% of all code on GitHub is AI-generated" is not the claim. It's more likely intended to be that 41% of *recent code* on GitHub is AI-generated, with how recent not being specified.

Comment: Not authoritative sources, but a comment on https://www.reddit.com/r/github/comments/14qwhem/how_does_github_know_41_of_all_code_on_it_is_ai and a comment on https://www.linkedin.com/posts/jimralley_holy-shit-41-of-all-code-on-github-right-activity-7081973527351828480-ONpv suggest it may be a misinterpretation of information about the GitHub CoPilot study group. I'm inclined to believe them due to the lack of any other sources claiming 41% of code is AI-generated.

Comment: I can accept students and learners who already learned about GitHub and then were trying new libraries in today's latest JS library, generating War and Peace worth of codes for test projects when they were just writing a couple of lines themselves. There were also crypto mining campaigns that created pull requests to exploit automated tests to run their mining code. It is possible that those students and malware writers then utilize CoPilot or other ChatGPT derivatives, which then counted as "AI-generated code".

Comment: Funny story, around 2009/2010 I ran a project called [Gitpan](https://github.com/evalEmpire/gitpan) which [imported every version of every Perl module into Github](https://github.com/gitpan). 36,000 repositories. This created [an artificial spike in Perl's popularity](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/25337x/a_more_accurate_perl_popularity_measure_github/) which got people very excited. It also broke Github pretty badly for a while; don't make assumptions about list sizes, kids! And that's why Github APIs now paginate.

Comment: My first question would be: how do you detect AI generated code?

Comment: @RobWatts I think your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: Where does the boundary lie between AI-generated code and other forms of machine-generated code (auto-generated file headers; output of tools translating from one language to another; code for generating state machines, UI code, and other boring things; genetic algorithms and other methods of automatically optimizing or selecting parameters based on trial and error; other things I have no idea about)?

Answer (score 31):

It's likely a misinterpretation. Scott Guthrie, Microsoft Executive Vice President of Cloud and AI, in [an interview at Morgan Stanley TMT Conference](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Investor/events/FY-2023/Morgan-Stanley-TMT-Conference) in March 2023 spoke about some statistics they saw for users of GitHub Copilot (a development tool that uses AI to provide code suggestions):

> We're now seeing the developers using GitHub Copilot are 55% more productive with it on tasks, and that's sort of measured by independent studies. And 40% of the code they're checking in is now AI-generated and unmodified.

So they're saying that 40% of *new* code from Copilot users is AI-generated, not 40% of all new code and definitely not 40% of *all* code.

Comment: From @thelawnet: "It should be noted that GitHub Copilot is an AI development tool developed by GitHub and OpenAI; it doesn't seem surprising that users use it for its intended purpose." (not sure why they wanted to edit it into my answer instead of just leaving it as a comment)

Comment: because your answer doesn't give any indication to the reader that 'GitHub Copilot' is in fact an AI tool.